# Compute statistics on a delta table in SQL in Databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I'm trying to compute statistics on a delta table in SQL from Databricks.

I do :

```
ANALYZE TABLE '/my_dir/my_table' COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

and I get an error message :

*Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'ANALYZE TABLE '/my_dir/my_table''*

But if I do for example :

```
DESCRIBE DETAIL '/my_dir/my_table'
```

then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation wasn't really correct - this command requires table to be registered in Hive Metastore/Unity Catalog to work. It doesn't work with paths right now.